# How to use Redux Persist in Next.js to load user data on every page visit using ApolloClient for API calls

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, react-redux, redux-persist

I'm using Redux Persist in my Next.js app, and I'm trying to figure out where to put some code that needs to run on every page the user visits. Here's the code:

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.user)

  const loadUser = async (token: string) => {
    const apolloClient = initializeApollo()
    try {
      const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
        query: CURRENT_USER_QUERY,
        context: {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `JWT ${token}`,
          },
        },
      })
      dispatch(SET_USER(data.currentUser))
    } catch (err) {}
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let token = getCookie('token')
    if (!user && token) {
      loadUser(token)
    }
  }, [dispatch])
```

This code calls an API to get the user data and then stores it in the Redux store if there's a token inside the cookie called 'token'. It works fine if I put it in the index.tsx file, but that's just for that page.

Where should I put this code so that it runs on every page that the user visits?

Here's my _app.tsx file for reference:

```
import '@/styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client'
import { useApollo } from '../lib/apolloClient'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from '@/redux/store'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist'

let persistor = persistStore(store)

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const apolloClient = useApollo(pageProps.initialApolloState)

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </ApolloProvider>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

If i try to put the same code here i get this error `Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>`